# MVVMCross WPF Value Converter with Tibet Binding Is Not Converting?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvmcross, valueconverter

I am trying to make a value converter which takes a `bool` and returns the negation of it.  The value converter itself is simple:

```
namespace MyProject.Core.ValueConverters
{
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Cirrious.CrossCore.Converters;

public class BoolNegationValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, bool>
{
    protected override bool Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !value;
    }

    protected override bool ConvertBack(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !value;
    }
}
}
```

I would like to bind the `IsEnabled` property of a button to a `bool` using this value converter.  I am using Tibet style binding as described [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding) and have read [this wiki page](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters) in full, as well as watched the n=4 and n=35 MVVMCross videos.  I followed along in the n=35 video exactly as Stuart was explaining, and my resulting `App.xaml` file looks like this:

```
<Application
x:Class="MyProject.WPF.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:mvx;assembly=Cirrious.MvvmCross.BindingEx.Wpf"
xmlns:core="clr-namespace:MyProject.Core;assembly=MyProject.Core"
StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <mvx:Import
            x:Key="ImportCoreProject">
            <mvx:Import.From>
                <core:ConverterMarker />
            </mvx:Import.From>
        </mvx:Import>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The class `ConverterMarker` is an empty `public` class sitting next to `App.cs` in my core project, as described in the video.  Here is the line in my view class which should use this converter:

```
mvx:Bi.nd="Command SetStartingPointCommand; IsEnabled BoolNegation(UseDefaultStartingPoint)"/>
```

I thought maybe there is an issue with registering this Value Converter on startup, so I tried adding this:

```
 protected override void FillValueConverters (IMvxValueConverterRegistry registry)
 {
     registry.AddOrOverwrite("BoolNegation", new BoolNegationValueConverter());
 }
```

To my `Setup` class, as described in the value converters wiki page, but it tells me that `there is no suitable method to override`.

If anyone could help me out here, I would greatly appreciate it.  If it helps, whatever is happening is leaving the button permanently disabled, no matter what the value of `UseDefaultStartingPoint` is.  Everything builds and runs, but the button is always disabled.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is there any trace? Is the ValueConverter being called? (e.g. if you put a breakpoint inside `Convert`). is it being constructed (e.g. if you put a constructor in it and add a breakpoint?). What happens if you bind the text of 2 labels to `Text UseDefaultStartingPoint` and `Text BoolNegation(UseDefaultStartingPoint)` - what do they show? If none of that helps, is there a complete sample app (one page with a checkbox and a button both bound to `UseDefaultStartingPoint`) you can post anywhere (e.g. to a GitHub repo)

Comment: Unfortunately, its confidential work related code, so I cannot post it online. its pretty simple though, just a `bool` property in the ViewModel, and the checkbox's `IsChecked` property is bound to that `bool`.  When I bind a textbox to `UseDefaultStartingPoint` it works fine and displays `true` or `false` and changes when I check the checkbox, but when I bind to `BoolNegation(UseDefaultStartingPoint)` it shows no text.  When I put a break point in the `Convert` method, nothing happened.  When I added a constructor and put a break point there, nothing happened either.

Comment: Is there any trace? It'd help to have a repro - doesn't have to be your full project... I guess it'll take 15 minutes to make one... I just don't have 15 minutes spare right now....

Comment: I really appreciate your help and your time, and I wish I could do that, but I am only allowed to use stackoverflow to post portions of my code, I can't post a full program to any one location. Strict rules, unfortunately. I promise I'm not trying to be difficult.  There is no trace, though.  It mentions nothing about ValueConverters anywhere in the debug output.

Comment: Actually it does say `failed to find combiner or converter for BoolNegation`, I hadn't switched to the correct ViewModel yet.  My apologies.

Comment: Now I'm confused what is/isn't happening by the comment conversation... regardless I can't repro your case without the code... ho hum - your rules. If it helps, you can get hold of the `registry` using code like https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Platform/MvxAndroidSetup.cs#L159 - good luck!

Comment: Again, I really apologize for that, not my rules at all.  However, I got it!  I'll post an answer in a second.  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `debug` output was telling me that it `failed to find combiner or converter for BoolNegation`.  I noticed in the source code for `MvxWpfSetup` that it does not contain either

```
protected virtual void RegisterBindingBuilderCallbacks()
```

nor

```
protected virtual void FillValueConverters(IMvxValueConverterRegistry registry)
```

Like the `MvxAndroidSetup` class does, so neither of these methods could be overridden in my `Setup.cs` class.  So all I did was add

```
    protected void RegisterBindingbuilderCallbacks()
    {
        Mvx.CallbackWhenRegistered<IMvxValueConverterRegistry>(this.FillValueConverters);
    }

    protected void FillValueConverters(IMvxValueConverterRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.AddOrOverwrite("BoolNegation", new BoolNegationValueConverter());
    }
```

To `Setup.cs` and also edited `InitializeLastChance()` as such:

```
protected override void InitializeLastChance()
    {
        base.InitializeLastChance();

        var builder = new MvxWindowsBindingBuilder();
        this.RegisterBindingbuilderCallbacks();
        builder.DoRegistration();
    }
```

And everything worked out.  I will have to manually add each converter I want to the `FillValueConverters()` method, but that will work, I checked.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'm a bit confused why https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.BindingEx.WindowsPhone/Import.cs isn't working for you - but can't debug it from here - so life goes on :)